# How to run a unique test in Adonis.js

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, adonis.js

I have a problem here. I need to test just the 'montagem-ambiente' without run 'usuario', but, when a run `adonis test` he will run all the test in the folder.

I already try `adonis test -f 'filename'` and `adonis test group 'filename'` and the path file, but i could not understand how these commands works.

seeing the `adonis test -h`i cannot understand how to solve my problem

In adonis docs, i dont find the answer

[Test images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4nT2.png)

In Adonis forum i see a topic with a same problem, but i cannot understand how to apply in my case

Some superhero over here can help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer...
Well... It's embarrassing but it can help someone who is just starting out like me...

Its just

`adonis test --files test/unit/montagem-ambiente.spec.js`
or
`adonis test -f test/unit/<name>`

I hope to help anyone!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run tests via `node ace test` command.

E.g. `node ace test -g "test my first test"` for use grep by test case name or `node ace tets -f "my_test.js"` for run a particular test class.

Please note that you need to have unique test cases names to be able to run one test using `-g` flag.

Answer (score 1):

For the new Adonis with ace command line, you could try `node ace test --tests 'Your test title'`

Try `node ace test --help` to see more options.

Comment: How can I run tests inside subfolders? I've tried all sorts of combinations and can't seemt to get it to work. Also do i need to put in the spec.ts in the string?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. need to use node ace test --files /path/path/test.spec.ts    No quotes around file name